# pandas dataframe Shape of passed values is (1, 4), indices imply (4, 4)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, shapes

I am trying to create a pandas dataframe with one row using and ended up testing the following simple line of code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4], columns=['a', 'b', 'v', 'w'])
```

Although this seems very simple i get the following error

```
Shape of passed values is (1, 4), indices imply (4, 4)
```

I have seen a few answers on this issues but all provide a way around it that doesn't explain why this happens and does not apply in my case.

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

you need to change the list of values to `[[1,2,3,4]]`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4]], columns=['a', 'b', 'v', 'w'])
```

Comment: I cannot i believe I lost so much time for such a simple thing! Thanks  lot!

Comment: Its still not clear to me "why this happens". I don't have such a straight-forward initialization, but a similar error message. What indices is the error message referring to? Why wouldn't the OP init result in a 1x4 df? Neither `[1,2,3,4]` nor `['a', 'b', 'v', 'w']` appears to imply a 4x4 shape, so why would you need to force it into such a shape by nesting braces?