# PySpark errors when trying to find the rows in a pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, shap

I have a PySpark dataframe `df` (`type(df)` is `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame`) and it has 4 columns. I'm trying to find the number of rows it has using `df.count()`, but I keep getting the error messages below.

```
WARN PythonRunner: Detected deadlock while completing task 24.0 in stage 4 (TID 28): Attempting to kill Python Worker
...
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 24.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 28)
...
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4,1), indices imply (4,4)
```

I read that the `ValueError` usually means there are 4 rows of (4,1), but the examples I saw to resolve this are for pandas dataframe. I'm not sure how to resolve this for PySpark dataframe.

Also, should I be concerned about the `deadlock` warning? Is it related to the `ValueError`?

**ETA:** Added the code that I have before calling `df.count()`. Basically, I'm trying to calculate SHAP values for my model based on the code in this [article](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/02/02/scaling-shap-calculations-with-pyspark-and-pandas-udf.html).

```
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_columns = ['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3', 'feature4']

def calculate_shap(iterator: Iterator[pd.DataFrame]) -> Iterator[pd.DataFrame]:
    for X in iterator:
        yield pd.DataFrame(
            explainer.shap_values(np.array(X), check_additivity=False)[0],
            columns=shap_columns,
        )

return_schema = StructType()
for feature in shap_columns:
    return_schema = return_schema.add(StructField(feature, FloatType()))

df = spark_X.mapInPandas(calculate_shap, schema=return_schema)
df.count()
```

Both `df` and `spark_X` are of type `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame`. `df.printSchema()` showed the 4 columns correctly.

**ETA2:** Thanks to the suggestion by @samkart, I enclosed `explainer.shap_values(np.array(X), check_additivity=False)[0]` with `[explainer.shap_values(np.array(X), check_additivity=False)[0]]`, and there is no more error. But the number of rows returned is only 18K, while I'm expecting 180M. Why is this so?

Comment: Could you please include the code you are running too? `df.count()` is an action so execution is triggered, but the actual code causing the error may be from earlier.

Comment: I've added the code before calling `df.count()`

Comment: i'm guessing the ValueError is from the vector function, not spark dataframe. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874117/pandas-dataframe-shape-of-passed-values-is-1-4-indices-imply-4-4) -- enclosing the `explainer.shap...` line in box brackets might do the trick

Comment: Thanks for this. I no longer get the error, but the number of rows returned is only 18K, while I'm expecting 180M. Not sure why this is so.

Comment: What is the row count of spark_X?